# Как задать URL пользовательскому типу записи в зависимости от прикрепленных к нему пользовательским таксономиям?

Tags: wordpress

**Я создал Custom Post Type (Хранилища) /storage/:**

[image: alt]

**Также к ним прикрепил Custom Taxonomies (Регионы) /storage/russia/moscow/:**

[image: alt]

Сейчас при добавлении любой записи у мене генерируется url следующего вида **/storage/my-post/**.

Как реализовать так, чтобы соблюдалась иерархия из таксономий и подставлялась в url?

Как получить такой результат: **/storage/russia/moscow/my-post** или **/storage/russia/my-post**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все мои проблемы решил плагин: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-permalinks/